# Pig/MapReduce Job Analysis Concept understanding required

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I am running a Pig Script on a file which is about 1.22 GB. The default chunk size is 64MB. I have 4 Data Nodes. The Pig script as a output produces 19 files.
When I run the Pig script and see the Job Tracker I see 6 Jobs.

```
       Jobid           Priority   User              Name          Map % Complete    Map Total   Maps Completed  Reduce % Complete   Reduce Total    Reduces Completed   Job Scheduling Information    Diagnostic Info

job_201207121202_0001   NORMAL    user     PigLatin:Analysis.pig    100.00%             20            20              100.00%              1               1                         NA                   NA
job_201207121202_0002   NORMAL    user     PigLatin:Analysis.pig    100.00%              5            5               100.00%              1               1                         NA                   NA
job_201207121202_0003   NORMAL    user     PigLatin:Analysis.pig    100.00%              2            2               100.00%              1               1                         NA                   NA
job_201207121202_0004   NORMAL    user     PigLatin:Analysis.pig    100.00%              2            2               100.00%              1               1                         NA                   NA
job_201207121202_0005   NORMAL    user     PigLatin:Analysis.pig    100.00%              5            5               100.00%              1               1                         NA                   NA
job_201207121202_0006   NORMAL    user     PigLatin:Analysis.pig    100.00%             5             5               100.00%              1               1                         NA                   NA
```

According to my understanding, since the input file size is 1.22 GB, and chunk size is 64 MB, there will be totally 20 blocks created for the file. I have a replication factor of 3. Since I will have a map job for each split, I will have 20 Maps jobs and the job_201207121202_0001 Job says that in the list above and is perfect. However Why am i seeing other 5 jobs and totally other 19 Maps tasks?
Can anyone please help me understand this. I thought that It would just have 20 map and 1 reduce job since 1.22GB/64MB ~ 20.

I am a Pig/Hadoop Beginner. Help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pig compiles a script into multiple map-reduce jobs, depending on the semantics of the script. Roughly speaking, a join is a MR job. A group is an MR job. Order is 2 MR jobs (one to sample the distribution). There are a few other operators that produce MR boundaries.

Comment: Thanks SquareCog. Now, it makes sense for all those extra Jobs. Where can I find this information? Is it by any chance documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to share you're pig script for anyone to give an answer with any real confidence, but most likely your script is complex enough that executing all the stages requires 6 map reduce jobs to complete

You can see that the second job that execute did indeed have 20 mappers running (1.22GB / 64MB = 19.52, which will require 20 mappers):

> NORMAL user PigLatin:Analysis.pig 100.00% **20** 20 100.00% 1 1 NA NA job_201207121202_0002

Beyond that who knows what else you were doing - did you submit the same script a number of different times with different input files?

Comment: No. I ran it only once. Yes, even I expected it to just have 20 Map and 1 Reduce jobs. And by the way its the First job that has 20 Map not the second.(Sorry, the way i pasted it looks that way.) Anyway I can share my Pig script. How should I attach a file to this?

Answer (score 0):

Pig is thin layer built to chain MR jobs .

For a MR job "chunk size"(block size technically) decides the number of mapper , but for pig MR is the basic unit not chunk size .

Depending upon what kind of ETL you are doing with data , pig will map that to either a single/chained multiple MR jobs .

For example :
A= LOAD '/input' using PigStorage('|') as (a:chararray)
Store A into '/output' ;
This pigscript simply spawns  Map only job not even reducers are used .

A script which used groupby , followed by a JOIN will spawn 2 MR jobs .

Every Operation supported by PIG can be mapped to MR :

1. Join : 1 MR
2. GroupBy : 1 MR
3. Filter : can be either done in Mapper or reducer Phase
4. Load : Mapper
5. Store : Mapper or Reducer
6. Foreach : Mapper or Reducer